# Hypixel skyblock help

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have several questions about hypixel skyblock

1. Where are the NPCs in the hub? (The ones that sell you stuff) I usually can’t find the ones I need (coordinations and/or screenshots would be helpful)
2. I am not level 5 for any of my skills so how can I get sugar cane, diamonds, and slimeballs?
3. What is the best/fastest way to get your skill levels up to level 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically mine as much iron and coal as possible to get to level 5 mining and then you can access the deep caverns, after that go to the diamond reserve and mine a bunch of diamond, before the diamond mine, theres the emerald mine where you can get a load of slimeballs and stuff.

to get sugar cane, go to the wheat area of the hub, in one of the corners then farm enough wheat to go to the 
barn. when you're here, farm as much material as possible to get your farming level up so then you can go to mushroom island. at mushroom island there is sugar cane that randomly spawns every few seconds, then with that sugar cane you can craft yourself a sugar cane minion to do it for you. you can also craft your own slime and diamond minions, although the slime minions do damage to you, so you might want to put them in a 5x5 box so they cant escape to your island

Answer (score 0):

2. It's pretty hard without being level 5. Grind mining/combat XP until you get to the deep caverns, which is pretty good for getting diamonds, armor, slimeballs, Redstone, and other helpful stuff. The deep caverns are also good for pre-level 16 combat XP grinding. An Aspect of the End is a pretty good mid-game weapon. It can 2-shot or sometimes 1-shot the Lapis Zombies. If you're above level 16, Aspect of the Dragons is one of the best weapons in the game, and grinding Zealots, in the end, is a good combat XP farming tactic.
3. Mining - just go to the mines. Combat - graveyard is good, spider den probably too hard. Farming - just go around town and farm wheat.